# Como corrigir Registro de Classe?

Tags: c#, classes

Estou tentando chamar um aplicativo externo a minha aplicação e quando chamo esse aplicativo recebo o erro a seguir.

***Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {7BB8A242-8662-40D0-A0E0-D796BF2162E7} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).***

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

*Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {7BB8A242-8662-40D0-A0E0-D796BF2162E7} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).*

Já mudei a plataforma do projeto para x86, e fiz o registro das bibliotecas via regsvr32 e caso essa informação possa ajudar a responder meu sistema operacional é 64bits.

Comment: Isso funcionou alguma vez? O projeto do ActiveX também é seu? Em que linguagem você implementa ele? Como você consome o ActiveX no C#; via importação de TLB? o ActiveX foi recompilado? Há alguns motivos pra ter esse problema mas pode ser ingrato sair listando... É melhor você dar mais detalhes sobre este ActiveX e também sobre a maneira que vc consome ele no C#.

Comment: no Visual Studio funciona normalmente e tem uma biblioteca que realiza a chamada desse aplicativo, porém ao publicar o site no IIS não funciona mais, o Projeto do Active X não é meu, esse aplicativo chama um leitor biométrico conectado via USB...

Comment: Envelopar num componente DCOM é uma opção?

Comment: vou pesquisar sobre isso... se tiver algum link ou resposta aqui do SO, agradeço desde já...